# Timer() fixedRateTimer set for 20 sec does not stop when onStop is triggered

Tags: android, kotlin, timer, kotlin-coroutines

I have a Timer set to take a time stamp every 20 seconds when the activity is active. 
It registers the time correctly, but when my Activity's onStop method is triggered it continues to run. I have confirmation that the onStop is triggered, but the timer continues forever. Here what I have in my Activity:

```
private lateinit var timer: Timer


override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    checkForUpdates(true)
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    println("super.onStop triggered")
    checkForUpdates(false)
    timer.cancel()
    timer.purge()
}

private fun checkForUpdates(daemonIsTrue: Boolean) {
        timer = fixedRateTimer("default", daemonIsTrue, 0L, 20000) {
            Coroutines.io {
                val dateStamp = DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC).toString("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                println("dateStamp at $dateStamp")  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Coroutines extension, just in case:

```
object Coroutines{
    fun io(work: suspend (() -> Unit)) =
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                work()
            }
}
```

Can anybody help me figure out how to properly stop this Timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating two `Timer` objects, via two `checkForUpdates()` calls, and you are only cancelling the second one. Perhaps get rid of the `checkForUpdates()` call in `onStop()`.